# SELECT multivalues from same table in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table. as a reference table for values in the system.

```
Item    Item_code
Turkey  c01
KSA     c02
USA     c03
NY      s01
JED     s03
Dubai   j01
London  j02
.       .
.       .
.       .
```

In the display page for users I want to show readable data " `KSA, NY ..."` not the codes. having the results in one row would save a lot code line.**I don't want to do 5 select statements to get each value separately**

example: I want to display the Item column of `c02, s01 and s03` in one row.

desired result :

```
first Item     second Item    third Item ...
KSA             JED           NY
```

this goes for 5 columns.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Looks like a pivot: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: How you know KSA is first item and JED second item  ... and so on ? explain your logic

Comment: Please explain the logic clearely

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza order doesnt matter.

Comment: But you have to explain a little more. Right now doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Uchiha_Itachi this table is used as reference for values in the my system. but in the display I want to show readable values for users not the codes used in the programming. if possible, having all values in one row saves lines of code.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza please read above comment. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about conditional `MAX()`

```
 SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN Item_code = 'c02' THEN Item END ) as first_item,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Item_code = 's01' THEN Item END ) as second_item,
        MAX( CASE WHEN Item_code = 's03' THEN Item END ) as third_item
 FROM Items
```

Answer (score 4):

One method uses conditional aggregation with the ANSI-standard `row_number()` function:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then item end) as item_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then item end) as item_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then item end) as item_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then item end) as item_4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then item end) as item_5
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by item_code) as seqnum
      from t
       where item_code in ('c02', 's01', 's03')
     ) t;
```

Comment: i dont see any repeat on `item_code` so partitioning wont work there. But of course question isnt clear on what is the logic

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . I see.  That changes the question a bit.

Comment: It works great! but I marked the first answer I got.

Comment: @ShB . . . The answers are different.  Juan's answer is correct if there is only one code that you want in the result set.  However, you specifically list three values and mention five subqueries, so it seems like there are duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think OP table is a conversion table so no duplicates. Like `{USA,  c03}` there isn't another `USA`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pivot table like so

```
select * from (
    select item, code from @table
) as x
pivot
(
    max(item)
    for code in (c02, s03, s01)
) as pvt
```